# Defining const static that needs setting up at runtime

Tags: c++, class, static

I'm making use of a class with a few utilities defined as static methods eg.

```
QDate SSIMUtils::ConvertSSIMDate(QString s) {
    QDate rtnDt;
    //...conversion code
    return rtnDt;
}
```

I would like to define a few constants in this class eg. LOW_DATE and was thinking of putting in something like

```
const static QDate LOW_DATE; // Need to set this somewhere to 1/1/1970
```

Unfortunately, I can't define it pre-compile time like I would say an int eg.

```
const static int SSIMUtils::myI = 4;
```

because it requires the use of a setDate method.

My question is how should I define a static const that I need to set up codewise, as the constant requires initialisation. I'd been thinking of defining it in the .h file eg.

```
const static QDate LOW_DATE;
```

then in the .cpp file, at the top, doing something like

```
SSIMUtils::LOW_DATE.setDate(1970,1,1);
```

But this is syntactically incorrect. What I'd ultimately like to do is use this constant in other classes eg.

```
if (myQDate.compare(SSIMUtils::LOW_DATE)==0) {
    // do something.
}
```

What's the right way to set up a constant value in a static class that you need to adjust at run time ie. like a constructor?

Comment: QDate has a constructor equivalent to setDate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, QDate has a constructor equivalent to setDate(), which allows for initialisation of a 'const' object.

You must declare your static constant the following way:

myclass.h:

```
#include <QDate>

class myclass {
public:
    const static QDate CONST_DATE;
};
```

myclass.cpp:

```
#include "myclass.h"

const QDate myclass::CONST_DATE(1970, 1, 1);
```

I tested this using a std::string instead of a QDate (no QT available right now), and it works just as you want.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where the necessary information for the
initialization comes, or rather, when it is available.  If it's
always available, *and* the type supports copy, then you can
just write a function which returns the initialized type:

```
namespace {
MyType getInitialized()
{
    MyType results;
    //  ...
    return results;
}
}

static MyType const lowDate( getInitialized() );
```

If it doesn't support copy, you can derive from it, providing
a specialized constructor:

```
class MyTypeInitialized : public MyType
{
public:
    MyTypeInitialized()
    {
        //  ...
    }
};
MyTypeInitialized lowDate;
```

This has the disadvantage of masking the true type from the
client code, but otherwise works well.

If the information isn't available until later; e.g. it depends
on command line arguments, then you may have to use a variant of
the singleton idiom, where you have two `instance` functions:
one of which takes the necessary arguments for initialization,
and must be called first.  (Or that may even be overkill; it
might be sufficient to have a global `std::unique_ptr<MyType
const> lowDate;`, and initialize that with an object newed at
the start of `main`.  The main different is in the client
syntax.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change something declared constant at run-time, by definition.

The closest you can get to run-time constant initialization is to initialize in a class'
constructor initializer list:

```
SomeClass(int constantValue) :
    myConstant(constantValue)
{
...
}
```

Given that you are building a static class, you are probably not constructing an object though. You can always resort to having a setter method which only allows setting the value once (in which case you can not declare the field const, obviously).

Comment: Thanks Saanti. I guess I'll use the class constructor to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, it is a constant, it cannot (should not) be changed once initialised. The only place that you can assign a value to a constant member variable is in the constructor (that is, without weird `const_cast`s).

Comment: And a weird `const_cast` would result in undefined behavior if the object itself were declared static.

Answer (score 0):

Your QDate may be trivial to construct -- using a static constant may not be better than creating a new date for that constant each time the function is called.

In the interest of answering the question, let's assume it is complex to construct and that a static constant is best idea. You can simply write:

```
QDate SSIMUtils::ConvertSSIMDate(QString s) {
    static const QDate LOW_DATE( /* ...construct it... */ );
    QDate rtnDt;
    //...conversion code
    return rtnDt;
}
```

*Note: Looks like SirDarius explained how you can construct this type directly, without an intermediate (+1), although a function-local static constant is generally much better than a global constant because global constants lead to some very tough initialization problems in C++.*

This creates a function local static which will be initialized once, and in a thread safe manner before it is read and when the function is called.

If the instance cannot be constructed easily, it helps at times to initialize using the copy constructor and then creating an accessory function:

```
QDate SSIMUtils::ConvertSSIMDate(QString s) {
    struct F { static QDate Low() { return ...; } };
    static const QDate LOW_DATE(F::Low()); // << initialize the constant using the copy ctor
    QDate rtnDt;
    //...conversion code
    return rtnDt;
}
```

So the short approach using the construction provided by SirDarius using a function-local-static is:

```
QDate SSIMUtils::ConvertSSIMDate(QString s) {
    static const QDate LOW_DATE(1970, 1, 1);
    QDate rtnDt;
    //...conversion code
    return rtnDt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the options and explanations Justin. Pete